# Forking processes for every task in Celery

Tags: memory-management, fork, multiprocessing, celery

I currently use a C extension library for Python, but it seems to have memory leaks.  Tasks that are run on my `celeryd` do something using this C extension library, and `celeryd` eats a lot of memory about a hour later.  I cannot patch this C extension library in many reasons, but instead I want to fork processes for every task in Celery.  Are there any such options for Celery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD` option or `--maxtasksperchild` celeryd switch.

To restart worker processes after every task:

`CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=1`

https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting

Comment: What are the potential downsides of forking for every new task?