# python celery max-tasks-per-child-setting default

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am using celery and i want to use the [max-tasks-per-child-setting](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting)
because some of the celery process get high memory usage.

I am trying to find the default value for this setting before i change but i cant find that information.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846978/forking-processes-for-every-task-in-celery) but i dont want to set it to `1` because i dont want it restarted every task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default there is no limit

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-max-tasks-per-child

You can check out all default config values from defaults.py

https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/defaults.py

```
>>> from celery import conf
>>> conf.CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD is None
True
```